# Linux perf on big applications

Tags: linux, perf

I recently ran Linux perf (more precisely `perf record -F 99 -g -- my_app`) on a large application - peak memory ~350Gbytes, about 3 days runtime.

My problem now is that the resulting perf.data (41Gbytes) seems almost impossible to read. I launched `perf report` over a day ago and the yellow progress bar is only on about 60%, and perf is using 0.467t VIRT and 0.411t RES according to top. The machine [RHEL 7.4 amd64] has 512Gbytes RAM and 256Gbytes swap. Fingers crossed that it finishes before being OOMed. I also tried `perf script`, but I had to give up when the output filled the disk mount (~550Gbytes). I'll try to find somewhere with more space, but considering that I was hoping to produce a flame graph, I'm not very confident that perl will be able to cope with the next 2 stages.

Obviously I can try to modify the parameters of my application to try to shrink the time and memory.

Any suggestions for options that would make `perf report` run more quickly and use less memory?

Comment: I'd guess that a lot of the memory pages it uses are pretty compressible, so if you don't have zswap set up already, that might help this workload fit into your 512GB more comfortably.  Arch Linux enables it out of the box in their kernels, but RHEL could be different.

Comment: Why you need perf record over all time of your application? Can you profile just several typical segments of it? Recording of stack traces with "-g" on very long runs generates lot of data; try not to use it for long records. For huge perf.data processing: compress output of perf script with something fast like zstd or lz4. There are also alternative perf.data parsers like perfparser([qt](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-cpu-usage-analyzer.html)) used in the https://github.com/KDAB/hotspot project (kdab hotspot probably will not be able to parse even 1 GB of perf.data, but the library may)

Comment: I'll take a look at perfparser and kdab hotspot. As for the first question, I do have some potential to perform partial runs, but it would be helpful to have a top-level view of a full run in order to know where to concentrate my research.